# QHBoxLayout внутри QVBoxLayout

Tags: qt, gui, layout

Проблема заключается в том, что при добавлении горизонтального лейаута в один из вложенных вертикальных происходит растяжение последнего. То есть колонки становятся неровными. На рисунке изобразил как задумано сделать. По факту вертикальная линия между колонками смещена вправо.
Как с этим бороться?

Схема такая:

```
QHBoxLayout
[
    QVBoxLayout
    {
        QHBoxLayout (вот тут засада);
        QGroupBox;
    }
    QVBoxLayout
        QGroupBox
]
```

Если убрать лейаут с пометкой "засада", то ширина колонок выравнивается.

[image: Вот как должно быть]

Comment: Использовать `QGridLayout`.

Comment: Такие потуги были, мало того что он так же терял выравнивание, так еще и нижняя граница групбоксов не совпадала (в разных строках же)

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь, то вижу два пути решения:

1. Используя `void QLayout::setContentsMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` добиться правильных отступов во всех "ячейках".
2. В лайаутах не "смешивать" виджеты и лайауты в пределах родительского лайаута.

Я бы посоветовал второй вариант. Иными словами если, например, нам нужно в QVBoxLayout разместить QHBoxLayout и QGroupBox, то следует поместить два QHBoxLayout, и в последний уже поместить QGroupBox.

А причина смещений, скорее всего, в наличии неучтенных/неравных отступов внутри лайаутов. По второму варианту эти отступы, по идее, должны быть везде равными.

Comment: К сожалению варианты не подошли. Решил через setStretchFactor. Указал внешнему род.  для левого и правого вложенных вертикальных лайаутов.

Comment: А можно прикрепить скриншот исходного состояния (со смещениями)?